# PHP select from DB and mantain the values without selecting again

Tags: php

I have a specific table in the DB that contains some static data.
This data is anyway required by many methods and each method calls the DB again and again to grab this data.

Now is there a way in PHP to select the data from the DB and mantain it as it was a constant or a SESSION ( I cannot use sessions in this case ) ?

What I am trying to do is to put the request in the contruct and to make the variable static, but it does not change the result. Each time a method calls the static variable, the select in the DB is done anyway..

```
class service {


    public static $actions;

    public function __construct() {

        self::$actions = self::getActions();

    }

    public static function getActions() {
        $actions = self::$db->select('_actions', '*');
        return $actions;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to cache the data using an external cache provider.

Comment: Are you talking about maintaining it across different script invocations, or just between different function calls in the same script run?

Comment: @Barmar just between different function calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is already pretty close.  You just need to add a check to see if the data has already been queried, and make sure you're using the static class variable, not a local variable.

You should realize that static variables and constructors live in two different worlds.  Static variables are persistent for the lifetime of the class - constructors run once per instance.

```
public static $actions = null;


public static function getActions() {
    if (self::$actions === null) {
        self::$actions = self::$db->select('_actions', '*');
    }
    return self::$actions;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be even simpler to put the `select()` in the constructor?

Comment: @Barmar - that would only work if he was instantiating a this class and storing that instance in a global variable - in which case he might as well just put his query results directly in a global variable.  Otherwise, every time he created a new instance of this class, he'd requery the data.

Answer (score 1):

Look into caching the data - http://www.phpfastcache.com/

You can use a library like the link above or write something simple that serializes the data and writes it to a file. If the file exists then use that data and deserialize it on subsequent requests for the same data set.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Sam Dufel's answer, but do the check and query in the constructor.

```
class service {


    public static $actions;

    public function __construct() {

        if (!self::$actions) {
            self::$actions = self::$db->select('_actions', '*');
        }

    }

    public static function getActions() {
        return self::$actions;
    }
}
```